# Automatic response when file is added to folder (Dropbox API)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, dropbox-api

So once the User has been authenticated and given an access token,

I want the user to be able to externally add a file into a Dropbox folder for example:
the user goes to dropbox.com, logs in and adds a new file called Dogs.png to a folder called Dogs

Then I want use the Dropbox API to somehow tell by backend that a file has been added to the folder Dogs, and then send some information about that file (e.g. filename) to the client.

This is a very conceptual post i'm quite new to these technologies, what's the best way to handle this problem, or am I thinking about it the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your app's server to be notified of changes in the accounts of users who have connected to your app, you should use [the Dropbox webhooks feature](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/webhooks). The documentation there covers how to register a URI for your server where Dropbox will send notifications for changes.

Note that those webhook notifications only tell *when* something has changed for a particular user, but not *what* has changed. To find out what changed, you can then call the Dropbox API, e.g., the [/2/files/list_folder](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-list_folder)[[/continue](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-list_folder-continue)] endpoints.